# Response.Redirect is not working with url rewriting or url masking

Tags: url-rewriting, response.redirect

I'm using link button for login. And I'm masking the url.

Here after validating and getting data from db I'm redirecting to another page using

```
Response.Redirect(".....");
```

But it's not redirecting...it's validating and getting data from db properly.

Can you suggest any solution for my problem.

Comment: May be this post will help u,                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441466/response-redirect-on-page-with-url-rewritten-by-iis-url-rewrite-module, will you please tell me that do you write relative path or actual path in Response.Redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.redirect("...") is a vbScript command for ASP.
You are showing a semi-colon in your example, which is JavaScript syntax but "response.redirect" is not a JavaScript command.
So... if you remove the semi-colon, your redirect will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is nested inside a conditional staement (like IF) then perhaps its not getting qualified, ie: the IF condition has not been satisfied.

Otherwise check your code... "response.redirect" looks to me like Classic ASP. For javaScript and other languages it will be a different function name.